# Delay to rerender view after each iteration vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, timer

I implemented a bubble sort algorithm and I am trying to rerender the ui after each iteration. Currently after running the function `runBubbleSort()` the algorithm is instantly terminated and the correct result is displayed. Is there the possibility to set a timer of 50ms before executing the next loop iteration?

```
runBubbleSort: function(event) {
    for (var j = 1; j < this.elements.length; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length - j; i++) {

            // set timer here

            if (this.elements[i] > this.elements[i + 1]) {
                var tmp = this.elements[i];

                this.$set(this.elements, i, this.elements[i + 1]);
                this.$set(this.elements, i + 1, tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You a couple of ways of doing this

1. [v-if directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) (bad way)

`v-if` directive that will only render the component when it's true. If it's false, the component will not exist at all in the DOM.

You can toggle a boolean variable to force it to rerender

```html
<template v-if="show">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</template>
```

2. [$vm.forceUpdate()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate) (better way)